# How can I get rid of the large blank space at the bottom of my website pages?

Tags: html, whitespace, removing-whitespace, cargo

I use cargo and my website has a large blank white space at the bottom of all the pages below the footer. I've looked through the CSS, and found that there were no footer inputted. I've tried inputting it myself according to some solutions that I found online who had similar problems such as:

```
#footer .content p {
    margin-bottom: 0
}
```

or experimenting with height, but none of them worked.

Please help me understand what I should do to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: Please share website url or screenshot so we can assist better. But it's worth checking extensions in your browser too. If it's adding some additional DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

There might be a given height in footer or its child element. or there may be a margin or padding associated with footer element. would you please share html part of footer. So that I can relate and check what is the exact bug creating white space.

Here is a list of possible bugs:
a) A bottom margin or padding in footer or its child elements or even it may be in body element.

b) A height may be creating white space

c) It May be due to some kind of overflow.

so, as a wrote before, share a screenshot or code of html part as well so that i can check and provide to the point answer

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying and helping me. As I am still new on this platform, there is not many things that I know yet. But would this be a code of the html? I could not insert a screenshot, but here is a link to it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn5hq.png

Comment: There is one div with the id = "following-container" just below the closing body tag </body>, Would you please tell what is that, or if you can just copy paste the html part here as you did for CSS.